# How can I search and replace wsdlLocation value of reference property in a soa config file

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I am trying to replace the ui:wsdlLocation value of the reference property in the composite.xml by using the config file.

This is the snippet from composite.xml:

```
<reference name="xyz"
             ui:wsdlLocation="http://www.example1.com/xyz/xyz.wsdl">
    <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/MIME_jws/xyz/xyz#wsdl.interface(xyz)"/>
  </reference>
```

I tried replacing the value in reference section of the config file as follows:

```
 <reference name="xyz">
    <searchReplace>
      <search>www.example1.com</search>
      <replace>www.example2.com</replace>
    </searchReplace>
   </reference>
```

But when I am trying the validate config plan option, it says

**Cannot use this deployment plan file. Schema validation error in File = .... at Line = 67 Column = 24:Element 'searchReplace' not expected.**

Can anyone please tell me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a deployment plan.xml to replace any end point server or URLs from composite. The replace activity used in deployment plan can override the design time URL and hence can point to a correct one.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
M S

Comment: Yes deployment plan is what I am using. But I want a way to replace the value of wsdlLocation  in the deployment plan.xml